# How to hide NavigationView's PaneToggleButton in uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using Windows template studio, in ShellPage.xaml, I can set NavigationView's PanToggleButton visible or not by using

```
IsPaneToggleButtonVisible=true/false;
```

And by default, my app will navigate to MainPage() after App started. When I navigate to Page1, I want to set `PanToggleButton` invisible.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. In ShellPage.xaml.cs,

```
private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SourcePageType == typeof(Page1))
        navigationView.IsPaneToggleButtonVisible = false;
    else 
        navigationView.IsPaneToggleButtonVisible = true;
}
```

Frame_Navigated method can get the navigated page type, and then you can do some more thing.